# What to do next when Managed Package reaches native Email limit

Tags: apex, email, managed-package, governorlimits, isv

My Managed Package is sending out email notifications using [`Messaging.sendEmail()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) and some Customer Orgs reach the [Governor Limits for native emails](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381534&type=1).

I know there is a myriard of **[API-driven Email Providers like Twillio Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/blog/powering-email-delivery-for-software-vendors/)** out there but I fear that integrating them into a Managed Package is everything but trivial.

**What is the best way to tackle this? How can I start simple and cheap and still have room for scaling in the future?**

*Things I am fearing a bit are:*

- How will an API service work with Callout limits in Salesforce?
- How will API Authentication work? Will I package a Named Credential?
- Is all of that packagable or will my subscribers have to setup up something on their end?

Comment: DailySingleEmailLimit is a limit that can be raised with a support case, justification, and assurance that you're not using email for marketing (transactional emails permitted, marketing, not so much). We considered a third party MTA but it added another moving part and while you can distribute the API key via managed package (either as a Protected CMDT record or Named Cred), the user will still need to approve the Remote Site manually

Comment: @daveespo how much were you able to move the limit? And is that documented anywhere?

Comment: Our operations team handles these requests -- the most recent case I was on regarding this was back in 2019 and it was raised to 10,000 per day -- I'm sure we've helped orgs get the limit raised many times since then. Salesforce is also much more willing to grant temporary increases rather than permanent ones.